# How to return the error type of lambda function?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

I was trying to call a boto3 api to stop a monitoring schedule. I was getting an error since that schedule doesn't exist. So I need to print the errorType. Is there any way to do that

**CODE**

```
import boto3
import sagemaker
from shared.logger import get_logger
from shared.aws import (deleteMonitoringSchedule,getMonitoringSchedules)

client = boto3.client(
                    'sagemaker',
                    aws_access_key_id='accesskey',
                    aws_secret_access_key='secretacesskey')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    response = client.stop_monitoring_schedule(
                MonitoringScheduleName="kk")
    return response["errorType"]
```

**RESPONSE**

```
{
  "errorMessage": "An error occurred (ResourceNotFound) when calling the StopMonitoringSchedule operation: Monitoring Schedule arn:aws:sagemaker:us-east-1:131132245555:monitoring-schedule/kk not found",
  "errorType": "ResourceNotFound",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 35, in lambda_handler\n    response = client.stop_monitoring_schedule(\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/botocore/client.py\", line 391, in _api_call\n    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/botocore/client.py\", line 719, in _make_api_call\n    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)\n"
  ]
}
```

Comment: You appear to be hard-coding AWS credentials in your Lambda function. There's no need to do this and generally you should not do it. Create an IAM role with the relevant permissions and then configure the Lambda function with that IAM role.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `try` and `except`:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    try:
         response = client.stop_monitoring_schedule(
                MonitoringScheduleName="kk")
         return response["errorType"]
     except Exception as e:
         return e.__class__.__name__
```

Comment: But with these, the output is "An error occurred (ResourceNotFound) when calling the StopMonitoringSchedule operation: Monitoring Schedule arn:aws:sagemaker:us-east-1:131132245555:monitoring-schedule/kk not found" which is the errorMessage, But I want only the ErrorType

Comment: @GovindSajeev Answer updated

Comment: can you also provide how to return the error message as you provided in the first stage.

Comment: @GovindSajeev I already answered your question correctly. If you have new issues, you should ask new questions.